# Не отображается верхняя граница у строки таблицы

Tags: html, css

Хочу при наведении указателя на строку в таблице обромлять её. Когда обромляю, она начинает прыгать, т.к. добавляется `1px`

Сделал везде белую границу, и при наведении меняю цвет, но, к сожалению, верхняя граница не показывается.

C `outline` решение не подходит, отображается двойная граница.

```css
tr {
  border: 1px white solid;
}

tr:hover {
  border: 1px black solid;
}

tr:hover td {
  border-top-color: black;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Пример на **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vemev90/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно при `tr:hover` у `tr` менять левый/правый `border`, а у `td` верхний/нижний. Таким образом и добьёмся желаемого результата.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
tr:hover {
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
tr:hover td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Пример на **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wx1udp9/)**